# Not route matches Error on api using date and latlong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes

I have a route for a service on my API set like this:

routes.rb

```
scope '(:locale)' do
  get 'api/categories/:category_id/subcategories/:subcategory_id/location/:lat/:long/date/:date' => 'api#get_providers_by_category_subcategory_location_and_date', defaults: { format: 'json' }
end
```

But for some reason it's not working and i keep getting the following Error:

```
RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/en/api/categories/1/subcategories/1/location/-34.5974909/-58.3798689/date/2014-12-12"):
```

Just in case, rake routes:

```
GET    (/:locale)/api/categories/:category_id/subcategories/:subcategory_id/location/:lat/:long/date/:date(.:format) api#get_providers_by_category_subcategory_location_and_date {:format=>"json"}
```

UPDATE:

full routes.rb file:

```
scope '(:locale)' do
  root to: "api#index"

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations", :sessions => "sessions"}

  get 'companies/index' => 'companies#index', defaults: { format: 'json' }
  get 'api/categories/:category_id/subcategories/:subcategory_id/location/:lat/:long/date/:date' => 'api#get_providers_by_category_subcategory_location_and_date', defaults: { format: 'json' }

end
```

Comment: You just missed forward slash before 'api'

Comment: Thanks @hkumar, but that didn't fix it. You meant at routes.rb, right?

Comment: just added full routes file on UPDATE

Comment: It's giving error because of your decimal in lat, & lang. Just try removing it & it will work.

Comment: Thanks, that made it. Btw, do you know the way to pass the latlong params correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work

```
scope '(:locale)' do
    get '/api/categories/:category_id/subcategories/:subcategory_id/location/*lat/*long/date/:date' => 'api#get_providers_by_category_subcategory_location_and_date', defaults: { format: 'json' }
end
```

Comment: This made it. Thanks @hkumar